# How to serverside order/sort query results in amplify-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm writing a facebook wall like function for my webapp with amplify-cli and vue, and I need to do a simple serverside orderby/sort in my query. It seems impossible..

I have tried the standard graphql way, with adding sort, it does not work...

The query generated by amplify-cli:

```
query ListWallposts(
  $filter: ModelWallpostFilterInput
  $limit: Int
  $nextToken: String
  ) {
  listWallposts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken
  ) {
  items {
    id
    content
    createdAt
    comments {
      nextToken
    }
    user {
      id
      firstname
      lastname

    }
  }
  nextToken
  }
}
```

My addition:

```
query ListWallposts(
   $filter: ModelWallpostFilterInput
   $limit: Int
   $nextToken: String
  ) {
  listWallposts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken,sort:{ field:createdAt, order:ASC }
  ) {
  items {
    id
    content
    createdAt
    comments {
      nextToken
    }
    user {
      id
      firstname
    lastname
    }
  }
  nextToken
  }
}
```

I can not add primary sortkey to dynamoDB, after amplify-cli table creation.
I have spent days trying to figure this simple thing out... Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB needs a global secondary index. The `@key` transform (or directive) can be added to your `schema.graphql` file as a sibling to the already existing `@model` transform.

[Key Directive Documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#key)

Regarding the definition below:

`directive @key(fields: [String!]!, name: String, queryField: String) on OBJECT`

The important thing is that the first element of the "fields" argument is the partition (or hash) key. Every subsequent element is a sort key. Together, the sort keys will determine the order or the returned results.

(Doing so with cause `amplify push` to create an entirely new GraphQL field on the `Query` type. The value of `queryField` will be the new field name. The `name` argument is the global secondary index name.)